# Why does sodium chloride not conduct as much as aluminum chloride in water?

Tags: ions, conductivity

I understand how $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{AlCl3}$ dissolves in water but I'm wondering why one is more conductive than the other. Is it their extra ions to conduct the electricity?

I know that in $\ce{NaCl}$ the water molecules 'steals' the Sodium or the Chloride depending on which end becomes closest to the material due to the Dipole-Dipole attraction. However, this reaction alone cannot break down the ionic lattice alone so there is a separate endothermic reaction. But I still can't understand the science behind why one conducts more than the other.

Comment: Your question might really benefit from adding more details, e.g. what do they conduct and in what conditions. Also, welcome to Chem.SE.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎

Comment: If the anions are identical, it must be due to the cations. What happens when you dissolve both salts in water?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha No, it isn't in this case.

Comment: @Kelsey ; clarify molar concentration of the solutions at the very least and if any other compounds are dissolved in the solutions

Comment: @permeakra Did I miss something? Under otherwise similar conditions, I would attribute the effect to the higher ion mobility of protons (hopping mechanism). $\ce{AlCl3}$ gives an acidic solution.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha You worded it in a very misleading manner.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha I don't think a high school student is going to be familiar with the Grotthuss diffusion mechanism. Heck, the people who wrote OP's textbook may not even know of it....

Comment: @permeakra Might be. An author tends to read what he has meant. The only misunderstanding I can think of is that somebody might mix both salts in the same beaker and add water. That's definitely not what I meant :D

Comment: @Brian You're probably right and I was just overdoing the problem. Counting ions might be good enough here :)

Comment: I'm guessing OP is asking about same concentration of the salt, not ions.

Comment: With all the discussions, we missed to tell you one important thing: **Welcome to Chemistry.SE!**

Comment: Make sure you note that aluminum chloride is actually $\ce{AlCl3}$.

Comment: Okay, so the reason that is important is because of the **van't Hoff factor**. Is the question more complicated than this or are the other folks here maybe going a little more in-depth than required?